# How to solve error "Subquery returns more than 1 row" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i made a query such as the following in codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT tanggal,
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) from absensi_siswa where kehadiran="alfa" GROUP BY tanggal ) AS alfa,
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) from absensi_siswa where kehadiran="izin" GROUP BY tanggal ) AS izin,
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) from absensi_siswa where kehadiran="hadir" GROUP BY tanggal ) AS hadir,
            ( SELECT COUNT(*) from absensi_siswa where kehadiran="sakit" GROUP BY tanggal ) AS sakit
            FROM absensi_siswa GROUP BY tanggal');
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: Congratulations. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your each sub clause `(select count(*) .. )` returns morethan 1 rows, From your query i assume you need individual counts based on different values of `kehadiran`, you simplify your query as

```
SELECT tanggal,
SUM(CASE WHEN kehadiran="alfa" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS alfa,
SUM(CASE WHEN kehadiran="izin" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS izin,
SUM(CASE WHEN kehadiran="hadir" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hadir,
SUM(CASE WHEN kehadiran="sakit" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sakit
FROM absensi_siswa 
GROUP BY tanggal
```

Using mysql you could make `sum` clause even shorter like `sum(kehadiran="alfa") as alfa`, Putting expression in `sum(a=a)` will return as a boolean 0/1 or true/false and you will get a count based on your expression